# login required error, when fetching calendar list

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to fetch the primary calendar in my nodeJS application, but its giving

> login required error
>   code: 401,
>   errors:
>   [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'required',
>          message: 'Login Required',
>          locationType: 'header',
>          location: 'Authorization' } ] }

following is the code

calendar.middleware.js

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/google/callback' //YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);
const SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
];

const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: SCOPES,
});
module.exports = {
  fetchToken: async function(req, res, next){
    console.log("fetchToken");
    const code = req.query.code;
    try{
        const token = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
        req.token = token;
        next();
    }catch(e){
      next(e);
    }
  },

  fetchCalendars: async function(req, res, next){
    console.log("fetchCalendars");
    const token = req.token;
    let cals;
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
    try{
      const calendar = await google.calendar({version: 'v3', oAuth2Client});
      cals = calendar.calendarList.get({calendarId: 'primary'});
      console.log(cals);
      next();
    }catch(e){
      next(e);
    }
  }
}
```

routes/index.js

```
...
router.route('api/v1/google/callback').get( calendarMiddleware.fetchToken,
                                      calendarMiddleware.fetchCalendars,
                                      calendarController.googleCallback);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'Login Required',

Means that you are not properly authenticating your request.  The following should be close

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), fetchCalendars);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function fetchCalendars(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  cals = calendar.calendarList.get({calendarId: 'primary'}), (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const items = res.items;
    if (items.length) {
      console.log('Calendar:');
      items.map((calendarList) => {
        console.log(`${calendarList.description} (${calendarList.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

The code above is pieced together form [Node.js quickstart Google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)  Its the best auth example for node.js that i know of.

Comment: Thanks Dalm, basically I started with the same quickstart example you mentioned in above answer, but I wanted to use, **async and await** instead of promises, so I changed the quickStart code as per the requirement.

Comment: Your question is about login required error message i have answered that.   I think you should open a new question about converting the code to use async await.  someone else may be able to assist you with that

Comment: I just now observed that, the token object i receved was not having refresh_token, do you have any idea why its not sending refresh token?

Comment: you need to request offline access if you have done that then have the user go to their google account and remove your access then request access again.  Some scripting languages only return the refresh token the first time the user is authenticated.   I think you can also use a promt force to force a reauth which may also return a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks Dalm, I ended up following the same pattern you mentioned above, however i will open a new issue for converting the code to async await.

Answer (score 1):

For async/await, try this:

```
google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client});
```

Instead of:

```
google.gmail({version: 'v1', oAuth2Client});
```

before fetching labels or emails.